# Visual Studio: How to put spaces before the text in a for loop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need your help with this problem. What I am trying to do is create a rectangle within the given coordinates or spaces. Here's my code so far, what am I missing here? Please see sample input and output below.

```
Dim d As String = ""
Dim s As String = ""
Dim counter As Integer = 0

For i = 1 To y
    s = s & vbNewLine
Next

For row = 1 To height
    For col = 1 To width
         If x <> 0 Then



         Else
             d = d & "X "
         End If
        Next
        d = d & vbNewLine
    Next
outputTBX.Text = s & d
```

Here is my sample input, however, if you look at the sample output, there should be 2 spaces before the X's. Thank you in advance!

Width: 4

Height: 4

X axis: 2

Y axis: 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below. I think you were missing the col offset loop that add spaces.

```
Sub Main
    DrawRectangle(4,4,2,2)
End Sub

Sub DrawRectangle(ByVal height As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) 

Dim d As String = ""
Dim s As String = ""
Dim counter As Integer = 0

' row offset
For i = 1 To y
    s = s & Environment.NewLine 
Next

' row loop
For row = 1 To height
    'col offset
    For i = 1 To x
        d = d & " "
    Next
    'col loop
    For col = 1 To width
         d = d & "X"
    Next
    d = d & Environment.NewLine 
Next

' uncomment outputTBX and comment console for your work
'outputTBX.Text = s & d
Console.WriteLine(s & d)

End Sub
```